# Firebase nesting data maintainability vs. filter using query performance?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Reading a lot around Firebase and structuring data, one question that's not clear is the best approach to structuring data either by nesting using keys or querying using a child key values. So I'm wondering where the trade-offs are and when you might consider one over the other?

To give an example, imagine you have 'boards' and 'notes' belonging to a user. A note can only belong to one board, do you nest the notes under a board unique key (option A):

```
notes : {
    [unique userKey] : {
        [unique boardKey] : {
            [unique noteKey] : {
                ...
            },
            [unique noteKey] : {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
},
boards : {
    [unique userKey] : {
        [unique boardKey] : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or do you use child values as a way to associate/query notes for each board (option B):

```
notes : {
    [unique userKey] : {
        [unique noteKey] : {
            ...
            boardKey: [unique boardKey]
        },
        [unique noteKey] : {
            ...
            boardKey: [unique boardKey]
        }
    }
},
board : {
    [unique userKey] : {
        [unique boardKey] : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The second option seems preferred [according to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data).

But here's my question, if there could be thousands of notes per board, which is better in terms of bandwidth cost/performance for things like retrieving/subscribing/editing/deleting - i.e.: If you wanted to update or delete all notes for a board, it seems like option A would be better as you're dealing with a more specific data tree (notes/[unique boardKey]/) as opposed to querying all games for the child key?

My main concern comes down to maintainability vs. performance of these two different approaches.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: As a side note, whilst boards and notes are a one-to-many relationship, I've not nested notes under boards because there's a scenario where I want to retrieve data about only the boards - nesting notes under boards would extend the tree and increase bandwidth / affect performance - I assume.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad topic that (while very interesting) does not lend itself to the simple Q&A format of Stack Overflow. The short answer is that the best structure depends on all of your use-cases, which we can't know (and likely neither do you at this moment). So design a starting model, see where that doesn't work and then ask concretely how to fix that. Good docs to start: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I realised as I was writing the question that it was a little open and "it depends" was likely the answer. I'll update to be a little more specific as my question really was if using queries to find/update/delete data was more costly in terms of bandwidth and performance than nesting the data?